# Controls created on runtime has no window. Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

i have button on the view and call following void to open popover controller with image picker, no problem here popover come up with image picker etc.

when i create UIButton programmatically on viewDidLoad the buttons calls same void below however this time that throws an exception "**Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.**"

```
-(IBAction)pickupPhoto:(id)sender
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 1, 1); // [(UIScrollView *)sender frame];
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
    self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    self.popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imgPicker];
    [popOver setDelegate:self];
    [popOver presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:[self view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:NO];
    [imgPicker release];
}
```

here i am creating buttons on same view buttons call the void.

```
-(void)addButtons
{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    self.btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 100, 0, 100, 80)];
    [[self.btn layer] setBorderColor:RGB(245, 245, 245).CGColor];
    [[self.btn layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [[self.btn titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Thonburi" size:70]];
    [self.btn setTitle:doubleToString(i+1) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btn setTitleColor:RGB(245, 245, 245) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btn setTitle:doubleToString(i+1) forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.btn setTitleColor:RGB(125, 225, 225) forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.btn addTarget:[NMBPostUI alloc] action:@selector(pickupPhoto:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
    [btn release];
    }
}
```

i can see when i call -(void)addButtons, self.view.window returns nil for the buttons created at runtime that causes the problem. yes i should create buttons during init but there is no init call when you call view controller as -storyBoard- Page Sheet. how can i walk around this?

any ideas are welcome.
many thanks.

Comment: ok, this time called from code and created buttons during init. nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating buttons in:

```
initWithNibName:bundle:
```

or

```
awakeFromNib
```

methods. Maybe this will work.